# virt-customize cant resolve packages

Tags: virtual-machine, cloud-init, proxmox

**command:**
 `virt-customize -a kinetic-server-cloudimg-amd64.img --run-command "apt-get install qemu-guest-agent -y"`

**stacktrace:**

[   0.0] Examining the guest ...

[   5.3] Setting a random seed
virt-customize: warning: random seed could not be set for this type of
guest

[   5.4] Running: apt-get install qemu-guest-agent -y
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...

E: Unable to locate package qemu-guest-agent
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...

E: Unable to locate package qemu-guest-agent
virt-customize: error: apt-get install qemu-guest-agent -y: command exited
with an error

---

tried different things related to virt-customize, tried mounting cgroups etc

**OS: proxmox 7.4.3**

**kernel: linux 6.2.11**

I have been breaking my head over this for several weeks now
I can provide verbose outputs but that might be too much

Answer (score 1):

Try the --install option:

```
sudo virt-customize -a kinetic-server-cloudimg-amd64.img --install qemu-guest-agent
```